# How to build simple google chart in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, googlevis

I am new to shiny and the googleVis packages, and I am trying to construct to create a simple, bare bones gvisMotionChart in Shiny.  I have been able to create the gvisMotionChart in a separate file, but when I try to run the Shiny app, it only displays the side bar panel and does not generate the animated chart.

ui.R

```
    library(shiny)
    library(googleVis)

    shinyUI(fluidPage( 
      titlePanel("Google Motion Chart"),
      sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel("Inputs go Here"), 
        mainPanel( 
          htmlOutput("view") 
        ) 
     )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)

shinyServer(function(input, output) { 

   output$view <- renderGvis({ 
      gvisMotionChart(Fruits, 
                    idvar="Fruit", 
                    timevar="Year") 
    }) 
})
```

Comment: Please try post an example with a R built-in dataset for example `mtcars`

Comment: Try using this as your base: `shinyApp(
  ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
    headerPanel("Google Motion Chart"),
    sidebarPanel("Inputs go Here"),
    mainPanel(
      htmlOutput("view")
    )
  )),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$view <- renderGvis({
      gvisMotionChart(Fruits, idvar="Fruit", timevar="Year")
    })
  }
)` and debug from there.

Comment: I have changed the post so that the example uses the built-in Fruits dataset.  The same problem occurs--when I try to run the Shiny app, it only displays the side bar panel and does not generate the animated chart.

Answer (score 0):

One needs to enter:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) { datasetInput <- 
reactive({gvisMotionChart(Fruits, idvar="Fruit", timevar="Year") })     
output$coolplot <- renderGvis ({ datasetInput() }) })
```